# Down the rabbit hole - Where does "res" originate from in express and/or nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I'm trying to understand more of the express and nodejs internals. Looking in express' `response.js` file, it frequently assigns several methods to `res`, which seems to be a prototype.

Specifically, `res` is declared as `res = http.ServerResponse.prototype`.

Ok, so what is `http`? `http` is declared as `http = require('http')`.

So looking in express' `http.js` file, we see `exports = module.exports = HTTPServer;`

and `HTTPServer` seems to be this method:

```
function HTTPServer(middleware){
  connect.HTTPServer.call(this, []);
  this.init(middleware);
};
```

And this is where I get stuck. According to my logic, it would seem that `ServerResponse` is being called on the `HTTPServer` method, which of course doesn't make sense. Therefore, I must be missing something.

UPDATE:

I just realized that express creates an instance of HTTPServer:

```
exports.createServer = function(options){
  if ('object' == typeof options) {
    return new HTTPSServer(options, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
  } else {
    return new HTTPServer(Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments));
  }
};
```

So I'm guessing it's the case that `ServerResponse` is actually being called on that instance? But I still cannot locate `ServerResponse`...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't see any http.js file in [express source files](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/tree/master/lib).

According to [node.js documentation on http](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http) `http = require('http')` will load the http module, which has a [`ServerResponse` object](http://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_class_http_serverresponse).

So express code enhances the ServerResponse object with additionnal methods.

Comment: ahhh you're right... forgot that because it's not `require('./http')` it loads the default module... duhh

Comment: Although my application has an http.js in the express folder... weird